# Qual è il significato di "snodo" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

In un articolo de *L'Espresso* ho letto:

> Quando Fiore arriva in gran segreto nella Londra di Margaret Thatcher insieme a Massimo Morsello e ad altri militanti di Terza Posizione, ad aiutarli - si legge in un rapporto sull'eversione nera firmato dai servizi segreti italiani (Sisde) del 1982 - è la League of Saint George, **snodo** internazionale della destra europea, di cui fa parte tra gli altri anche l'ex presidente del British National Party Nick Griffin.

Ho cercato il termine "snodo" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato o non ho saputo trovare nessuna accezione che abbia senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: mi potreste spiegare qual è il significato di "snodo" nella frase precedente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato **snodo** ha il senso di punto di incontro, collettore, punto di riferimento.

Su Treccani puoi trovare altri esempi di utilizzo:

> Trieste come [**snodo**](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/atlante/geopolitica/Trieste_i_nodi_del_vertice_sui_balcani.html) europeo fondamentale, naturale punto
> d’incontro delle culture latina, mitteleuropea e slava, saldatura
> geografica e geopolitica tra un blocco europeo che già c’è

ed anche:

> Gibuti, [**snodo**](http://Gibuti,%20snodo%20dell%E2%80%99espansione%20cinese%20verso%20l%E2%80%99Africa%20e%20il%20Mediterraneo) dell’espansione cinese verso l’Africa e il
> Mediterraneo

Ovviamente in questi esempi il termine snodo è riferito a luoghi mentre nel passaggio da te citato in modo figurato ad una organizzazione.